What force or field is associated with the weak hypercharge?
So what is the force or field associated with the weak hypercharge in post-SSB?

When you appreciate weak mixing through the Weinberg angle, you'll see how weak hypercharge is involved in both the photon and the weak neutral boson Z...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

A clip from wikipedia:
Weak hypercharge is the generator of the U(1) component of the electroweak gauge group, SU(2)×U(1) and its associated quantum field B mixes with the W3 electroweak quantum field to produce the observed Z gauge boson and the photon of quantum electrodynamics.
The weak hypercharge satisfies the relation:
$$ Q = T_3 + \frac 1 2 Y_W $$
so it's the Z-boson.
Back when I did parity violating elastic electron-proton scattering:
$$ e^-p \rightarrow e^-p $$
where at the tree level, the parity violation comes from interference between $\gamma$-exchange and $Z^0$-exchange ($t$-channel), I would kind of think of the $Z$ as a heavy photon, so a Yukawa-like potential with exponential suppression:
$$ V(r) = g\frac{e^{-r/M_Z}}r$$
from which you can derive a "force field" concept. Given the range:
$$ \frac{\hbar c}{M_Zc^2} \approx 
\frac{0.2 \rm\,GeV\cdot fm}{91\,\rm GeV} = 0.002\,{\rm fm} $$
the force field mental picture isn't that useful, but that's no reason not to think about it.

So weak hypercharge is the "associated charge" of the Z boson field? Which mediates the weak neutral current?

Z is for sure the weak neutral current. I'm not to current on the weak sector, so check an amplitude (e.g., beta decay), and see what the coupling constant is. Comment the result, too, and I can add it the answer (with citation, ofc).

Actually, both the $\gamma$ and $Z^{0}$ couple to the weak hypercharge.  That is the crux of electroweak mixing.

@Buzz wait, So we have charge, weak hyper charge, weak isospin three, all not linear independent. What is the same of the mixture of the latter two that is orthogonal to charge?  BTW: I should know this, I tell people light bulbs emit $W^0$ boson (mixed, ofc).
